# Intercepting exit()

Tags: c++, libc

I have a class that may be something like this:

```
class StreetSim{
  public:
  void operator(){
    //do cool things
    if(street_exploded) exit(5);
  }
};
```

This works great for a small program like this:

```
int main(){
  StreetSim ss;
  ss();
  return 0;
}
```

However now I want to embed this in another program.  I would really like to not fork the process as a child, but I'm not allowed to change `StreetSim`.  I would prefer something like this:

```
int main(){
  StreetSim ss;
  int k = catch(ss());
  if(k==5) 
    fprintf("the street exploded!");
  return k;
}
```

Is it at all possible to catch a program exit signal like this?  I suspect not, but perhaps some gurus here might have some useful tribal knowledge about something like this.

Comment: StreetSim should throw an exception instead of `exit(5)`! It's a really bad idea to put `exit` in something like this. It hurts reusability.

Comment: You *can* catch `exit` calls with [`std::atexit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit), but there's nothing you can really do about the axtual "exiting", the program will still terminate.

Comment: elaborating on @Joachim's point: Trying to get around it with exceptions will just terminate the program anyway. Also, you would have UB if a `setjmp`/`longjmp` pair might omit calls to non-trivial dtor.

Comment: I suggest return a status code from the `operator()` function.  This will allow callers of the function to perform error handling without using the exception mechanism (or other complicated means like messing with the `exit` function).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843189/exit-call-inside-a-function-which-should-return-a-reference/22843464#22843464

Comment: So that bit about not being able to change `StreetSim`... But this atexit call look like it has promise if it catches the exit *before* the memory and classes are destroyed.

Comment: Can you define very precisely what the restriction is on "change"? For example, can you modify an include file to contain `#define exit(x) throw(x)`? Can you link it in such a way that `exit` is hooked?

Comment: The library is already compiled, but I *can* change the header files.  Subverting the linker is an interesting idea, but I don't think that `#define` alone will do the trick.