# Is there a way to get exit code before program ends?

Tags: c++

Some legacy code, I have to wade through, unfolds some kind of problem to me. At the moment I can't change to behavior, but I can change the surrounding code.

The legacy code starts a `std::thread`, which might fail and calls `std::exit`. I have to know the exit code emitted to write a JSON dump for automatic computation after my program ended. This mechanism works just fine, but not if the thread calls `std::exit`.

Lets break it down to following.

```
#include <thread>
void func() {
    try {
        // do something, that also might fail
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e) {
        // process the error
        std::exit(-1); // exit with what ever exit code chosen
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1{ func };
    shutdown_dump dump;
    // --> register function with 'shutdown_dump' to notice exit is called and get return code emitted.

    // do some other work
    // but thread fails and ends before join
    t1.join();
    dump.set_exit_code(0);
    return 0;
    // dump is created in dtor of 'dump'
}
```

To clarify again, I CAN'T pass dump to my thread (at the moment this is unchangeable legacy code). I'm not willing to use a `singleton`, which could solve the problem in some kind of way, but it adds much more problems to worry about. And yes, it is planed to rework the legacy code, so please don't get the conversation stared this way. (Doesn't everyone have to deal with some legacy code? :D )

So can I register a function somewhere, to notice `std::exit` is call AND get the return code? Unfortunately `std::atexit` doesn't offer the retrieval of the emitted exit code.

I can use every feature `c++14` has to offer. It should work for visual studio (windows) and clang (linux) compiler. I'm willing to implement two versions for each OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercepting exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27323156/11683)

Comment: @GSerg no, it does not concern an thread and it has no answer

Comment: Can you run your program inside another program, which handles the exit code and writes the dump?

Comment: @vll All the code depends on a driver, which sadly can't be used twice for the same hardware.

Comment: @skratchi.at with all the constraints I think that the only option is to refactor the legacy code.

Comment: @Scheff "I" do not do it. I just have to handle the sh* given to me, which at the moment I can't change.

Comment: Ah, OK. That explains... ;-) I should have read the text around the code sample...

Comment: @freakish It occurred to me too, but it was worth a shot. Maybe there was a quick shot, to fix this, in the time I refactor the code.

Comment: How Standard does it need to be? In the end, `exit()` on both platforms is a library function, and you can use platform-specific library tricks to provide your own interposer.

Comment: You can't change `void func()` to `int func()` and `std::thread t1` to `auto t1 = std::async(func);`?