# Matrix Class Error: Expression:_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

this is my first time of using stackoverflow, nice to meet you all.
I am writing a matrix class that overloads assignments,addition, subtraction...etc. 
The assignment operator "=" overloading part seems to work fine, but if I attempt to overload the addition "+" operator, I get error message like this:

"Debug Assertion Failed!
Program:...nts\C++\week6....\week6matrix.exe

File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgdel.cpp

Line:52

Expression:_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)"

But if I remove "delete[]matrix" in my destructor, everything seems to work, but due to the requirement of this project, I needed to have this term in my destructor.

I would have posted a picture but its my first time of using this website, so I don't have the reputation to do that yet so I apologise if my question doesn't seem to make sense, but I ll try my best to explain it if you have any further questions regarding my question.

Thank you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
//dynamic matrix
class dymatrix
{
  friend ostream & operator << (ostream &os, dymatrix &om);
  friend istream & operator >> (istream &is, dymatrix &om);
private:
  int rows;
  int columns;
  double *matrix;
public:

  dymatrix(){cout<<"Default constructor called"<<endl; columns = 0; rows=0; matrix=0;}
  dymatrix(int inrows, int incolumns)
  {
    rows = inrows;
    columns = incolumns;
    matrix = new double [inrows*incolumns];
    for (int i=0; i<inrows*incolumns; i++) 
    { 
        matrix[i]=0;
    }
  }
  int lengthr() const {return rows;}  //Returns number of rows.
  int lengthc() const {return columns;}   //Return number of columns.
  dymatrix& operator=(dymatrix&);
  ~dymatrix(){cout<<"Destructor called"<<endl;delete[] matrix;}  

  int index(int i, int j)  //This member function returns the position of each index.
  {
    if (j > 0 && j <=rows && i > 0 && i <=columns)
    {
        return (i-1)+(j-1)*columns;
    }
    else {cout<<"Error, out of range"<<endl; exit (1);}
  }
  double & operator()(int i, int j) {return matrix[index(i,j)];}  //The operator () returns the position of j and i in 1D array.

  dymatrix operator + (dymatrix &arr)  //overloading addition.
  {   

    if (rows !=arr.rows && columns != arr.columns)
    {
        cerr<<"SIZE DO NOT MATCH, YOU FAIL"<<endl; exit(1);
    }
    dymatrix new_matrix(rows,columns);
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.rows*arr.columns; j++)
    {
        //for (int i = 1; i <= arr.columns; i++)
        //{
        //cout<<"****"<<j<<endl;    
        new_matrix.matrix[j]= matrix[j]+arr.matrix[j]; //Putting in the data into this dynamic array for each element.
        //}
    }
    return new_matrix;
  }

};  //Class end.
  dymatrix & dymatrix::operator = (dymatrix &arr) //Overloading "=" operator.
  {
    if (&arr == this) return *this; //If the array is the same, no need to change, just to print. The key word "this" is a pointer to the object, and *this gives the object.
    delete[] matrix; matrix =0; rows =0; columns =0;
    rows = arr.rows;   //Setting row length.
    columns = arr.columns;    //Setting column length.
    if(rows*columns > 0)
    {
        matrix = new double [rows*columns]; //Defining a dynamic array here.
        for (int j = 1; j <= rows; j++) //Assigning each term to each term.
        {
            for (int i =1; i <=columns;i++ )
            {
            matrix[index(i,j)] = arr(i,j);  //This is the assigning part, the loop above loops everything so that each term is assigned.
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;   //Return
  }

  istream & operator >> (istream &is, dymatrix &om)   //Overloading ">>" operator here to
  {
    cout<<"Please enter the number of rows you want"<<endl;
    is >> om.rows;  //Inputting number of rows.
    cout<<"Enter the number of columns you want"<<endl;
    is >> om.columns;   //Inputting number of columns.
    cout<<"Enter matrix"<<endl;
    om.matrix = new double [om.rows*om.columns];    //Making a dynamic array here to put the data in.
    for (int j = 1; j <= om.rows; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= om.columns; i++)
        {
            is >> om.matrix[om.index(i,j)]; //Putting in the data into this dynamic array for each element.
        }
    }
    return is;
  }
  ostream & operator << (ostream &os,   dymatrix &om)  //To output the matrix in an standard matrix way
  {
    for(int j= 1; j<=om.rows; j++)
    {
        os<<endl<<endl;
        for (int i = 1; i <=om.columns;i++)
        {
            os << om.matrix[om.index(i,j)]<<"\t";   //Similar method used in istream.
        }
    }
    return os;
  }
int main()
{
  dymatrix a1;
  cin >> a1;  //Define the rows of the matrix
  cout << a1<<endl<<endl;
  dymatrix a2;
  cin >> a2;
  cout << a2<<endl<<endl;
  dymatrix resu_a1;
  resu_a1=a1+a2;
  cout<<"Addition = "<<resu_a1<<endl;
  dymatrix resu_a3;
  resu_a3 = a1;
  cout<<"Assigning = "<<resu_a3<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This is my destructor:

```
~dymatrix(){cout<<"Destructor called"<<endl;delete[] matrix;}
```

This is when I overload the assignment "=" operator(outside the class) which seems to work:

```
dymatrix & dymatrix::operator = (dymatrix &arr) //Overloading "=" operator.
  {
    if (&arr == this) return *this; //If the array is the same, no need to change, just to print. The key word "this" is a pointer to the object, and *this gives the object.
    delete[] matrix; matrix =0; rows =0; columns =0;
    rows = arr.rows;   //Setting row length.
    columns = arr.columns;    //Setting column length.
    if(rows*columns > 0)
    {
        matrix = new double [rows*columns]; //Defining a dynamic array here.
        for (int j = 1; j <= rows; j++) //Assigning each term to each term.
        {
            for (int i =1; i <=columns;i++ )
            {
            matrix[index(i,j)] = arr(i,j);  //This is the assigning part, the loop above loops everything so that each term is assigned.
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;   //Return
  }
```

But when I  overload the addition operator "+" inside the class, I get the error which I quoted above.

```
dymatrix operator + (dymatrix &arr)  //overloading addition.
{   

    if (rows !=arr.rows && columns != arr.columns)
    {
        cerr<<"SIZE DO NOT MATCH, YOU FAIL"<<endl; exit(1);
    }
    dymatrix new_matrix(rows,columns);
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.rows*arr.columns; j++)
    {
        //for (int i = 1; i <= arr.columns; i++)
        //{
        //cout<<"****"<<j<<endl;    
        new_matrix.matrix[j]= matrix[j]+arr.matrix[j]; //Putting in the data into this dynamic array for each element.
        //}
    }
    return new_matrix;
}
```

This is my int main:

```
int main()
{
  dymatrix a1;
  cin >> a1;  //Define the rows of the matrix
  cout << a1<<endl<<endl;
  dymatrix a2;
  cin >> a2;
  cout << a2<<endl<<endl;
  dymatrix resu_a1;
  resu_a1=a1+a2;
  cout<<"Addition = "<<resu_a1<<endl;
  dymatrix resu_a3;
  resu_a3 = a1;
  cout<<"Assigning = "<<resu_a3<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `dymatrix & dymatrix::operator = (dymatrix &arr)` function parameter should be const reference (or by value if performing copy and swap idiom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning copies of your matrix when you call `operator +`, but your `dymatrix` lacks a user-defined copy constructor:

```
dymatrix(const dymatrix&);  // this is the missing function
```

You must implement this function to have a return-by-value of your `dymatrix` to be correct.  Without this function, your code will exhibit undefined behavior, and will more than likely crash when it comes time to object destruction (double deletion errors and/or memory leaks).

Look up the "Rule of 3".  If you implement a user-defined assignment operator, then a user-defined copy constructor and destructor should also be implemented:

[What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

The easiest way to do this is to move most (if not all) of that code from your `operator=`, to the copy constructor.  Then implement your `operator=` in terms of the copy constructor using the `copy/swap` idiom:

[What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

As to your implementation of `operator=`:  why are you doing all of that work to copy from one array to another?  It should be a straight loop, going from 0 to `rows*columns`. You shouldn't need to call all of those extraneous functions to get the `index` and so forth.

But going back to the copy constructor, it would more than likely look like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
dymatrix::dymatrix(const dymatrix& arr) : 
        rows(arr.rows), columns(arr.columns),
        matrix(new double[arr.rows * arr.columns])
{
   std::copy(arr.matrix, arr.matrix + rows*columns, matrix);
}
```

Now your assignment operator can be coded like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
class dymatrix {
   //...
    dymatrix& operator=(dymatrix arr); // use this version of assignment operator
  //...
};

//...
dymatrix& dymatrix::operator=(dymatrix arr)  
{
   std::swap(rows, arr.rows);
   std::swap(columns, arr.columns);
   std::swap(matrix, arr.matrix);
   return *this;
}
```

---

The other point is that you should have implemented `operator+=` before you implemented `operator +`.  The reason is that you could then write `operator +` in terms of `operator +=`, thus creating two operators, with `operator +` being essentially a 3 line function (the code in your current `operator +` would be moved to the `operator +=`.

---

Another point is that your `operator+` should pass a `const dymatrix&`, instead of `dymatrix&`.  You are not changing the parameter within the function, so it should be passed as `const` reference.

---

The last point is that if the matrices are not the same size when you add them, your code should throw an exception -- it should *never* just exit the program as your code is doing, and especially not within a class.

This should explain why you should never do this (I know it is probably a school exercise, but it is such a poor thing to do):

[exit() call inside a function which should return a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843189/exit-call-inside-a-function-which-should-return-a-reference/22843464#22843464)

Comment: Thank you so much, this got rid of the error message.The only problem left is that the addition of 2 matrices gave me a memory location. I did do a cout inside the "addition" overloading function to check whether if it was returning a correct value which it did, but the cout in my main function gave me a memory location :s

Comment: I edited my answer to correct the call to `copy` in the copy constructor.  Your code should output correctly now.